# Что выбрать: nUnit vs xUnit?

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, xunit

В чём разница между [nUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) и [xUnit.net](http://xunit.codeplex.com)?

В чём вообще смысл развивать два, а не один: я вижу, что xUnit развивается автором of nUnit:

> xUnit.net is a unit testing tool for the .NET Framework. **Written by**
>   the original **inventor of NUnit**

С другой стороны:

> NUnit - фреймворк для написания юнит-тестов для .Net языков .. текущая продакшне версия (version 2.6) -- это седьмая мажорная версия **основанная на xUnit**

В общем где правда?

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [nUnit vs xUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9769047/5752652) от участника  [@Ruslan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192384/ruslan).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9769047

Answer (score 9):

Вас смущает то, что название конкретного фреймворка (xUnit) совпадает тем, как называют целый класс инструментов предназначенных для написания юнит-тестов (JUnit, NUnit и т.п.), где x в названии означает что там может быть подставлено название конкретного языка/среды.

Оба этих фреймворка являются великолепными, они оба например поддерживают паралельный запуск тестов (хотя и разными способами).

**NUnit** был основан в 2002 году, широко распространён, хорошо документирован и имеет большое сообщество, в то время как **xUnit.net** более современный, более ориентированный на подход TDD и более гибкий и более широко использующийся в .net core. (Комментарий от АК: не забывайте пост написан в 2016 году, четыре года назад)

В дополнение к этому замечу, что главное отличие которое я заметил состоит в том, как xUnit.net запускает тестовые методы. Так в **NUnit** у нас есть тестовый класс и набор тестовых методов в нём. NUnit создаёт экземпляр тестового класса и запускает все тесты этого класса на одном и том же экземпляре. В то время как **xUnit.net создаёт экземпляр тестового класса на каждый тестовый метод. Поэтому в тестах не получится использовать поля и свойства для обмена данными между методами (что в общем-то плохая практика с точки зрения TDD и тестовые методы должны быть независимыми друг от друга с точки зрения методологии TDD). Так что используя xunit.net вы можете быть уверены что ваши тестовые методы полностью изолированы.
Если же вам захочется иметь общие данные для тестовых методов, то xUnit позволяет вам это сделать. Поэтому по умолчанию все методы полностью изолированы, но вы можете использовать и другой подход, если укажете явно. (В комментариях 2019 года указывается что это описание также является устаревшим)

Также см. сравнение xUnit и nUnit: https://codopia.wordpress.com/2017/02/20/xunit-net-vs-nunit-a-pragmatic-comparison/ (2017 год)

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [nUnit vs xUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9769047/5752652) от участника  [@akazemis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3795379/akazemis).</sub>

Comment: маловато фактов. не хотите дополнить от себя? особенно в части того, что именно устарело в этом сравнении

Comment: @Anatol Особо ничего не меняется в этих фреймворках, нового нет, старое не удаляется, разве что поддержка .core добавляется и всё. Живут своей зрелой жизнью. И каждую операцию можно сделать и в том и в этом фреймворке, есть даже табличка сравнения: https://xunit.net/docs/comparisons Я вот как сижу плотно на одном из фреймворков так и нет повода слазить: всё настолько хорошо работает, что ни разу не появилось мысли "а не посмотреть ли другой?", уверен, что то же самое и насчёт другого у тех кто сделал другой выбор. Ну разве другой проект/работа где другой тулчейн - а так "работает - не трогай".

Comment: спасибо за ссылку, но там скорее таблица соответствий, чем сравнение